# Changing colors of antdesign header

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, less, antd

I am trying to change background color of entire header in antdesign. I am not sure but file with defaults should be this https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less

I found out that color of header is used here so i changed it to red

[image: antd defaults]

Global.less

```
@import "./vars.less";

@layout-header-background: red;
```

But its override with another class [image]

Now my question is what is best practice to achieve change of header color.
[image: I mean this thing here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The background color of the `<Header />` can be simply change using JSS or put a class on it:

```
<Header style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}>...</Header>
```

or

```
<Header className="red-header">...</Header>
```

and in css

```
.red-header{
    background-color: red;
}
```

maybe what are you seeing is the color of the `<Menu/>` component. You can also modify the color of it using JSS or put a class on it:

```
<Menu style={{backgroundColor: "red"}} mode="horizontal">...</Menu>
```

see sample here

[image: Edit]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There is only one downside with first code you shared and the problem is i cant use less variables there. Anyway i thought the right way is to edit antd variables instead of creating new classes. Again thank You .